# Does user network speed have an impact on web server performance?

Tags: performance-testing

The Slow Loris attack overwhelms an unpatched web server by simply extending the time it takes to finish making a request, then repeating that action - thus tying up all available resources to respond.

It follows then, that many users from geographic locations with bad internet connectivity, should be similarly detrimental to performance.

Is this really the case? What is the phenomenon called? What is a good way to simulate this with a load testing tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone who opens a connection to the server takes a connection out of the webserver's [connection pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool), normal person makes a request, quickly gets response and closes the connection (as long as the browser doesn't send [Connection: keep-alive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header)

The point of [Slowloris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)) DOS attack is to use all the connections and retrieve the data at minimum speed (i.e. 1 byte per second) so request which normally finishes in a couple of seconds will "hang" for several hours.

It shouldn't have impact on the server's performance, i.e. it will be continuing serving other users normally, however server can run out of available connections and maybe run out of memory given it keeps the response in the memory until it's released.

You can use any of tools listed under [Similar Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)#Similar_software) wikipedia article:

[image]

If you're looking for a load testing tool which can simulate slow connections "in addition" to the "normal" load testing features you can take a look at [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) in general and in [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test) article in particular.